# How to return a mixed set ,from two types of documents at specific positions ,in mongodb and nestjs?

Tags: mongodb, merge, pagination, nestjs, aggregate

My stack is NestJs and MongoDb.I have a schema of named **Post**. And the post can be of two types one is of **video** and the other is of **ad**. And all the videos and ads are present in a single collection of **Posts**. The documents are only distinguished by a property `postType`.It's a string property in `Post` schema so can user set type as video or ad. Now I have to return a `mixedUserFeed` from mongodb with pagination.

**I want to order the documents in such order like first there will be an ad at top, then 5 videos and then again an ad and 5 videos and so on like following**

```
1st ad
video
video
video
video
video
2nd ad 
video
video
video
video
video
3rd ad 
video
video
video
video
video
.
.
.
.
so on...
```

**Also there are two conditions.**

```
if(ads >= videos) 
ad
video
ad
video
ad
video
.
.
.

if(ads < videos)
1 ad and 5 videos like I explained above.
```

I can do this with loops but the thing is all the data will be inside memory then.And that will be a disaster. And also I won't be able to use mongodb pagination of any type keyset etc...And I have to make some kind of custom pagination.

**I want to do the mixing on db level so I also can use pagination easily on a mixed ads and videos set.**

**So far I'm only able to do that all the ads are at top and videos are beneath the ads documents.**

```
async getMixedFeed() {
    const pipeline: any[] = [
      {
        $facet: {
          videos: [
            { $match: { postType: 'video' } },
          ],
          ads: [
            { $match: { postType: 'ad' } },
          ],
        },
      },
      { $project: { documents: { $concatArrays: ['$ads', '$videos'] } } },
    ];

    return this.postModel.aggregate<any>(pipeline).exec();
  }
```

**OR**

```
async getMixedFeed(pageNumber: number) {
    const videosPerPage = 5;
    const adsPerPage = 1;
    const skipVideos = (pageNumber - 1) * videosPerPage;
    const skipAds = Math.trunc(skipVideos / videosPerPage) * adsPerPage;

    const pipeline: any[] = [
      {
        $facet: {
          videos: [
            { $match: { postType: 'video' } },
            { $skip: skipVideos },
            { $limit: videosPerPage },
            { $addFields: { type: 'video' } }, 
          ],
          ads: [
            { $match: { postType: 'ad' } },
            { $skip: skipAds },
            { $limit: adsPerPage },
            { $addFields: { type: 'ad' } }, 
          ],
        },
      },
      { $project: { documents: { $concatArrays: ['$ads', '$videos'] } } },
    ];

    return this.postModel.aggregate<any>(pipeline).exec();
  }
```